# Should I use a second table for Extra account information after customer signs up?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, ruby-on-rails-4

Im very new to this programming malarkey and have a quick question regarding my users information.  My users table currently has columns for about 9 different specifics... first name, last name, gender etc.  I want my sign up form to only have 3 fields, with the rest being filled in on their first time logging in.

Is it more efficient to just leave my table as is, or to have one table for the initial account info and have a second table using a foreign key for the secondary info.

As far as i can tell, all the fields belong in the user table, but that means upon creating a new user some columns will be left blank and I'm pretty sure i read that was a bad thing :)

Excuse the basic question.  Like i said very new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank columns are blank if they stay blank. You should consider it only if a) most users won't fill out the additional info b) you ain't gonna use it normally.

Basically you shouldn't be worried about efficiency and go with normalized design until you notice you are having performance problem and you notice this is the case.